# ActionBar or Layout

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am making an app that has many activies. The main one has a tab viewer and some of these tabs have buttons that launch another actiivies. In this activies I had put a LinearLayout at the top of the screen with an arrow to the left, and when the user press it, it returns to the main activity. My question is: Is that a good way to achieve what I want or should I use a customize ActionBar for those secondary activies?

I don't have anyt problems right now, just curious about the best programming practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating explicit layouts and buttons to return to a single main activity is not good practice, as you're going to create more overhead for yourself for each child activity you add.

As you probably know, Android provides an easy way to navigate back to the main activity via the action bar.

All you need to do is add the parent activity to the child activity's manifest, and then call getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true) in your activity's onCreate() method. Your activity will need to either use a theme derived from the Holo theme or extend the ActionBarActivity class using the support library.

This is less work and less likely to be error prone than manually adding an extra LinearLayout and button code for each child Activity that is effectively re-implementing this behavior.

For more information see the "Add up Button for Low-level Activities":

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html